# gparted gpt table is corrupt after restart?

Tags: debian, hard-disk, gparted

i had problems with gnome disk utility and switched to gparted for my external drives

after the restart i get some error messages one of them is this one
"the backup gpt table is corrupt.." or "not all of the space available.." i checked
with "mount", "parted --list" ,"cat /proc/mdstat" but found no errors, why i got problems with both programs now and got error messages after fresh install of gparted?

Comment: Can you post these error messages in full? And the output of the other programs? You mention mdstat, are you using FakeRAID? If you enabled RAID in the BIOS it corrupts the GPT. Both RAID metadata and GPT backup are at end of drive so they are in conflict - until you partition the RAID instead of individual drives (the RAID being a few sectors smaller than the whole drive). But in Linux you should not be using this type of RAID anyway, just go with native mdadm...

Comment: What does gdisk show? `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` More info:http://askubuntu.com/questions/386752/fixing-corrupt-backup-gpt-table/386802#386802 If RAID you may need mdadm, see man page.